# Not getting output though code compiles successfully

Tags: verilog, quartus

I am trying to implement 8 bit conditional sum adder and the code compiles successfully in the quartus 2 but the output I am getting is xxxxxxxx for everything. Don't know whats wrong.
**// Module for 8-bit conditional sum adder**

```
module csa1(a,b,cin,sum,cout);  
parameter W=8;  
**// Inputs declarations**  
input [W-1:0] a, b; // Two inputs a and b with a carry in cin  
input cin;  
**// Outputs declarations**  
output reg [W-1:0] sum; // Sum and carry cout  
output reg cout;  
**// Intermediate wires**  
wire s1_0, c2_0, s2_0, c3_0, s3_0, c4_0, s4_0, c5_0, s5_0, c6_0, s6_0,c7_0,s7_0, c8_0;  
wire s1_1, c2_1, s2_1, c3_1, s3_1, c4_1, s4_1, c5_1, s5_1, c6_1, s6_1, c7_1,s7_1, c8_1;  
**// Intermediate registers**  
reg fcout;  
reg s3_level_1_0, s3_level_1_1, s5_level_1_0, s5_level_1_1, s7_level_1_0,s7_level_1_1;  
reg c4_level_1_0, c4_level_1_1, c6_level_1_0, c6_level_1_1, c8_level_1_0,c8_level_1_1;    
reg c2_level_1;  
reg c4_level_2;  
reg s6_level_2_0, s6_level_2_1, s7_level_2_0, s7_level_2_1, c8_level_2_0,c8_level_2_1;  
**// Level 0**  
always @*  
{fcout,{sum[0]}}=a[0] + b[0] + cin;  
**// Conditional cells instantiation**  
conditional_cell c1( a[1], b[1], s1_0, s1_1, c2_0, c2_1);  
conditional_cell c2( a[2], b[2], s2_0, s2_1, c3_0, c3_1);  
conditional_cell c3( a[3], b[3], s3_0, s3_1, c4_0, c4_1);  
conditional_cell c4( a[4], b[4], s4_0, s4_1, c5_0, c5_1);  
conditional_cell c5( a[5], b[5], s5_0, s5_1, c6_0, c6_1);  
conditional_cell c6( a[6], b[6], s6_0, s6_1, c7_0, c7_1);  
conditional_cell c7( a[7], b[7], s7_0, s7_1, c8_0, c8_1);  
**// Level 1 muxes**  
always @*  
case(fcout) // For first mux  
1'b0:{c2_level_1,sum[1]}={c2_0,s1_0};  
1'b1:{c2_level_1,sum[1]}={c2_1,s1_1};  
endcase  
always @* // For 2nd mux  
case(c3_0)  
1'b0: {c4_level_1_0, s3_level_1_0}={c4_0, s3_0};  
1'b1: {c4_level_1_0, s3_level_1_0}={c4_1, s3_1};  
endcase  
always @* // For 3rd mux  
case(c3_1)  
1'b0: {c4_level_1_1, s3_level_1_1}={c4_0, s3_0};  
1'b1: {c4_level_1_1, s3_level_1_1}={c4_1, s3_1};  
endcase  
always @* // For 4th mux  
case(c5_0)  
1'b0: {c6_level_1_0, s5_level_1_0}={c6_0, s5_0};  
1'b1: {c6_level_1_0, s5_level_1_0}={c6_1, s5_1};  
endcase  
always @* // For 5th mux  
case(c5_1)  
1'b0: {c6_level_1_1, s5_level_1_1}={c6_0, s5_0};  
1'b1: {c6_level_1_1, s5_level_1_1}={c6_1, s5_1};  
endcase  
always @* // For 6th mux  
case(c7_0)  
1'b0: {c8_level_1_0, s7_level_1_0}={c8_0, s7_0};  
1'b1: {c8_level_1_0, s7_level_1_0}={c8_1, s7_1};  
endcase  
always @* // For 7th mux  
case(c7_1)  
1'b0: {c8_level_1_1, s7_level_1_1}={c8_0, s7_0};  
1'b1: {c8_level_1_1, s7_level_1_1}={c8_1, s7_1};  
endcase  
**// Level 2 muxes**  
always @* // First mux of level2  
case(c2_level_1)  
1'b0: {c4_level_2, sum[3], sum[2]}={c4_level_1_0,s3_level_1_0, s2_0};  
1'b1: {c4_level_2, sum[3], sum[2]}={c4_level_1_1,s3_level_1_1, s2_1};  
endcase  
always @* // 2nd mux of level2  
case(c6_level_1_0)  
1'b0: {c8_level_2_0, s7_level_2_0, s6_level_2_0}={c8_level_1_0, s7_level_1_0, s6_0};  
1'b1: {c8_level_2_0, s7_level_2_0, s6_level_2_0}={c8_level_1_1, s7_level_1_1, s6_1};  
endcase  
always @* // 3rd mux of level2  
case(c6_level_1_1)  
1'b0: {c8_level_2_1, s7_level_2_1, s6_level_2_1}={c8_level_1_0, s7_level_1_0, s6_0};  
1'b1: {c8_level_2_1, s7_level_2_1, s6_level_2_1}={c8_level_1_1, s7_level_1_1, s6_1};  
endcase  
**// Level 3 mux**  
always @*  
case(c4_level_2)  
1'b0: {cout,sum[7:4]}={c8_level_2_0, s7_level_2_0,s6_level_2_0, s5_level_1_0, s4_0};  
1'b1: {cout,sum[7:4]}={c8_level_2_1, s7_level_2_1,s6_level_2_1, s5_level_1_1, s4_1};  
endcase  
endmodule  
// Module for conditional cell  

module conditional_cell(a, b, s_0, s_1, c_0, c_1);  
input a,b;  
output s_0, c_0, s_1, c_1;  
assign s_0=a^b; // sum with carry in 0  
assign c_0=a&b; // carry with carry in 0  
assign s_1=~s_0; // sum with carry in 1  
assign c_1=a | b; // carry with carry in 1  
endmodule
```

Comment: Do you have a testbench for this design?

Comment: can you explain what you did actually?

Comment: `**// comment **` is not legal comment syntax. Is that how you really codded it or were you trying to make it appear **bold**? After removing all the leading `**` and putting it into a simple test-bench, it compiles fine and I don't see any Xs.

Comment: I do have a testbench @Unn , I am implementing a 8 bit conditional sum adder as mentioned in the title. Thanks for response I got in working now :)